# actor model in Thingsboard

Tags: akka, actor, thingsboard

if we have a very small configuration of TB (a base system is installed) and there are a few of IOT devices, 
what the initial number of actors, and how the number of actors is changed if there is a load from devices.

What is the difference between a Device Actor and a Session Actor?

Comment: What is TB? Clarifying this would help people help you.

Comment: I suggest to add thingsboard tag to the question

Answer (score 1):

ThingsBoard(TB) creates one device actor per each connected device. Similar, we have a session actor for each open session, but we are going to remove session actors starting TB 2.2, because we are separating transport layer (MQTT, CoAP, HTTP) to separate microservice and will use Kafka for communication.

Comment: what is the best way to monitor actors in things board platform and record their metrics? I read about some open source tools like Kamon for actor monitoring in an application, are anyone implements integration these tools with things board?